# Why does regex not match this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing following regex for validating Different currency entries in excel sheet format:

```
/^((\s*[\$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(\s?\d{3})*)(,\d+)?[\$]?(\s*[sSrR]\s*(\d+|(\d+-\d+)))?)|((\s*[\$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(\s?\d{3})*)(,\d+)?[\$]?(\t\s*[\$]?[+-]?\d*|(\d{0,3}(\s?\d{3})*)(,\d+)?[\$]?)*[\n\rx]*)+))$/
```

This regex is generated by following javascript code:

```
var groupingSeparator = "\\s";  // For euro currency
var decimalSeparator = ",";  // for euro currency
var NUMBER = "\\s*[\\$]?[+-]?\\d*|(\\d{0,3}(" + groupingSeparator + "?\\d{3})*)(" + decimalSeparator + "\\d+)?[\\$]?";

this.basicNumberRegExp = NUMBER;
var REPEAT_NUMBER = NUMBER + "(\\s*[sSrR]\\s*(\\d+|(\\d+-\\d+)))?";

var EXCEL_LINE = NUMBER + "(\\t" + NUMBER + ")*";
var EXCEL_MULTI_LINE = "(" + EXCEL_LINE + "[\\n\\rx]*)+";
var ret = "^((" + REPEAT_NUMBER + ")|(" + EXCEL_MULTI_LINE + "))$";
```

It should validate following entries:

```
3r3
-3r3
333
-333
333,33
-333,33
333 333
-333 33
```

But it is not matching/validating the following value, What is the reason:

```
-3r3
```

Comment: Should `$-3r3` validate too?

Comment: @revo No.. I have put the patterns in the question

Comment: Not all patterns. Your current regex implies a preceding `$` that you didn't point out. Currently it matches entries like `$-33`.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on this regex, seriously. It's not well written. It matches more than it should and it fails matching on some expected values leaving matching process with a *catastrophic backtracking* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a pair of parentheses.

You defined

```regex
var NUMBER = "\\s*[\\$]?[+-]?\\d*|(\\d{0,3}(" + groupingSeparator + "?\\d{3})*)(" + decimalSeparator + "\\d+)?[\\$]?";
```

Too long, but it's basically

```regex
var NUMBER = "(...) | (...)";
```

In the statement

```regex
var REPEAT_NUMBER = NUMBER + "(\\s*[sSrR]\\s*(\\d+|(\\d+-\\d+)))?";
```

, `REPEAT_NUMBER` is defined as

```regex
"(...) | (...)(...)?"
```

which is parsed as (because `|` has a lower precedence than concatenation)

```regex
"(...) | ((...)(...)?)"
```

Adding a pair of parentheses will work. Define

```regex
var NUMBER = "(\\s*[\\$]?[+-]?\\d*|(\\d{0,3}(" + groupingSeparator + "?\\d{3})*)(" + decimalSeparator + "\\d+)?[\\$]?)";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBda8IwFIbv/RUhCG0aq4NellG2kYGgMqrCwHQS06x2aFvS1jnU394lrW518@5w8n48Jx9sx3Iu46ywkzQUVbVjEkQyLbM4iaYiY5IVqQT3AFKaQxeAwQA8q4UoZQp4KaVI@FdHm0LB4y3bXHl6Z8f7TcdkPn4kvtaZKtxaUNoNvAW2A4/S0DqqZXi46zknEwJ8gwkDqIUH54QsVGv@IWCNHWLkNdkIup1OsY7z/orlMZ@U25WQvojIPlMUDY5bo/nkhTzMlj@E5wFfUPOp9AM9aUhco2K7rkLI0y06hLw@kdFyNJyQvwmFpv3dIAu6Lcd4PpoNLz5YX9aKUnp1TUKp3AcWwmenFIUWv5m1/BpfNxxbMa18/YS6GpinSZ5uRH@TRqZhO9Ix@ltW8LWZiE/Q/JGpSnpGZKgbq@ob)

Comment: Remark: Use `String.raw` to prevent double-escaping.